# How to format json data in miliseconds to Date format in highcharts?

Tags: date, highcharts

I get array of date from json as  1420185600000,1420531200000,1420617600000,1420704000000,1420790400000,1420876800000. How do I format it to show the correct date in the XAxis labels of the highcharts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell highcharts that the xAxis is a date [`type`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type).

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

You may need extra formatting if you want the date displayed in some form other than the default. That can be done via the [`labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter).

Sample code that lets you do what you want (minus what formatting you want your date in):

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [1420185600000,1420531200000,1420617600000,1420704000000,1420790400000,1420876800000],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return new Date(this.value);
        }
    }
},
```

You would then need to determine what parts of your new date string you actually want to show. The sample above doing `return Date(this.value)` is the kitchen sink approach.

UPDATE: If you want the strings formatted, Highcharts gives you functions to set up the date string.  See this fiddle (same as fiddle linked in the comments below with formatter using highcharts): http://jsfiddle.net/CaptainBli/psd3ngsh/13/

```
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
        categories: xArray,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.time.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L', new Date(this.value));
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I cannot use the datetime and categories at a same time right? How should I pass the values to the xAxis?

Comment: Thanks. I have two arrays ...dateArray and valueArray. I am having trouble with putting dateArray to x Axis

Comment: @Hary, how are you doing it currently?

Comment: xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime' categories:data.xArray
},  series:[data:data.valueArray]

Comment: What does your complete code look like. What is data.xArray? What is data.valueArray? We need to see how these are made.

Comment: I am getting data.xArray and data.yArray from the ajax call . So basically I have two arrays data.xArray looks like this and this is date [1420185600000,1420531200000,1420617600000,1420704000000,1420790400000,1420876800000]  data.yArray looks like [90,20,80,120,90,90]. Each values go with respective dates..And these arrays are dynamic. So how would I put the dynamic array in categories

Comment: See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/psd3ngsh/ with an array set to the `xAxis.categories` parameter. I would verify that your `data.xArray` is really an array and not just a list of strings.

Comment: I am sorry.its just a list of strings..Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayOfDatesFromJson = arrayOfDatesFromJson.map(function (element) {
  return new Date(element);
});
```

Comment: I have all the dates in array named xArray. so if i do xAxis{categories:data.xArray} the date labels on the xaxis are in milli seconds. How do I get the real date ?