# Highcharts multiple values for 1 date?

Tags: date, highcharts

I have multiple readings for same day. When I plot the dotted chart, I get one date for each value. So I have same date on x axis repeating for the number of readings for that same day. Is there any way I can put all the readings for a same day under 1 x-axis date label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be advisable to use a 'datetime' [`xAxis.type`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) in this case and send in your data as [time, value] pairs. Alternative would be to create multiple series with the xAxis index/value pairs needed - but this gets ugly quick.

Comment: I have two arrays..one for time and another for value...I am using the category to populate the x axis. Can I use categories and datetime at a same time?

Comment: The problem with categories is that highcharts not recognise "the same category strings". So you need to parse it on your own or use other type of xAxis.

Comment: @Hary I already answered how to make it show dates when using categor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990297/date-in-highcharts/27991153#27991153