# Highcharts: One xAxis as a Datetime without Constant Interval for 10 Series

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-boost

I've been looking for several days.  Trying many different solutions.

I need to be able to specify the xAxis as an array of dates that are not always consecutive (thus no pointInterval and no pointStart).  Otherwise my data gets way out of hand because I have more than 10 possible series across 100k+ points, with only 2 or 3 series shown at a time.  If I have to include dates for each of the points across each of the series that is too much wasted memory.  One simple case had over 3.2 million data points with three gaps of time (4 different sections of time based data).

The closest I have found is the [Date as a category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27991153/1280057) solution.  Where the xAxis has to have her own formatter in order to portray the millisecond timestamps as dates.

This doesn't really solve the problem because I don't want to reinvent the functions that highcharts has for formatting the datetime of the labels based on the zoom level of the graph.  And I don't want a single time format for all zoom levels.

So what I need to know is there a way to specify the datetime as an array for the xAxis without the need to add the datetime to every point and not use categories as this doesn't format the date correctly that works with boost.

I played with this fiddle (non-boost):
http://jsfiddle.net/psd3ngsh/13/

```
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
        categories: xArray,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.time.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L', new Date(this.value));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use timestamps for each point? If you won't supply `x` values, then Highcharts will assign index number as `x`. For example `[15, 10, 5]` will be actually treated as `[ [0, 15], [1, 10], [2, 5] ]`. IMHO 3.2 million of points is just too much to display on a small chart; 100k per series is too much to for a div with width e.g. 500px (200 points per pixel).

Comment: I suggest to use Highstock with build-in `dataGrouping`. Just tested how long it takes to generate series from a simple format (assuming it's from AJAX response): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sx01jLk6/ - less than 400ms and ~1s for chart generation. Similar results for Highcharts with Boost module: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dh9qa3np/

Comment: In assigning the x value to each of the 10+ series one has to build an array with an x and y value times 100k+ points per series is now double the size to pass around to the generation of the chart.  With boost and with zooming the user can see a days worth of data or down to the second.  Though you do bring up a good point.  I could add the series after the chart is built one at a time and then the discarded generated array will be garbage collected and I can create the next series to add to the chart.  3.2M points comes from 11 series and ~275k points, zoomable to view down to the second.

Comment: Highstock would be great though the cost is another $3000 on top of the other needs for heatmaps, gauges and bar charts. And that might end up being the way I have to go for this chart.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't copy `series.data` array, uses this as reference to improve performance (see: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dh9qa3np/15/) and it won't be GC'ed. Don't use the same variable (array) to generate different series by muting inner arrays (`series[0].data[index] = [ ... ]`). The only bottleneck I see here is data delivery (AJAX?) which can simply pass simplified dataset (see my demos first part). That dataset can be preprocessed to the Highcharts format (second part of my demos). AFAIK you can upgrade Highcharts -> Highstock. No need to buy two licenses (Highstock and Highcharts)

Comment: When using the heatmap the data gets converted to bloated objects instead of using the simple array of data.  I guessed that the same thing occurred with the line charts.  We will make the data in the form required by the chart.  After exhausting all other methods of trying to use a single simple array for the xAxis, we will replicate the x data across all of the different series so that the data lines up correctly with missing time slices.

Comment: FYI: Only boost module prevents from creating `Point`-class objects (that bloated objects you mentioned) and storing them. In boost module, `Point` objects are created on demand (e.g. when tooltip is displayed).

Comment: We have already given up on the heatmap as it is incapable of handling our number of data points even with boost.  We simply use it as a shell so that we can render to it.  We would suggest a few more mods to the heatmap in boost to reduce the overall data set when rendering more that what is visible to something like 4 times the width of the graph and then allow zooming until the data needs to be more dense and then switch to all the points when in the zoomed in views.  This would make your graph faster.  Ours is at least 100x faster.

Comment: I would also suggest a way to provide the actual x axis datetime as a single array for large amounts of data, and then the series' single dimensional array of values can match the x values (like categories).  By the time I am done with the charts I will have a possible 50 or so series with over 200k points per series.  The user will not have all of these open at once and will be zooming on this data to investigate specific sections.  Having to replicate the x date values 50*200k is a lot of extra data.  I did come across another option: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading

Comment: Could you share your ideas for improving heatmap? You can send them directly to our [support by email](https://www.highcharts.com/support) (please include URL to this question). Regarding lazy-loading, it's another, strongly recommended, solution for loading millions of points. This solution works great with huge datasets, but again, requires Highstock (as long as you want a way to zoom out, using Navigator).